# How do you print a function's content?

Tags: formatting, printing

Sorry if this is a newbie question, but I could not find a solution.

Say I have two functions, like:

```
A[x_, y_] := x + y^2;
B[a_, b_] := Integrate[A[x, 1], {x, b, 2}];
```

How would I go about printing the function `B`?

Actual output:

```
B
```

Ideal output:

```
4 - b - (b ^ 2) / 2
```

Basically I'd like to print the body of the function in simplified format, expanding my function calls and integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
?? A
```

(*

A[x_,y_]:=x+y^2

*)

```
?? B
```

B[a_,b_]:=!(
*SubsuperscriptBox[([Integral]), (b), (2)](A[x, 1] [DifferentialD]x))

or just `A[x,y]`, which gives:

$x + y^2$

Never use upper-case letters for functions or variables, since they are likely to conflict with *Mathematica*'s internal symbols.

Also, you define B as an integral, so that is the function.  If you want to *evaluate* that first, you must do:

```
B[a, b]
```

$-\frac{b^2}{2}-b+4$